# Python edit and append values to 1 string from json file

Tags: python, arrays, json, string

I have the json file `badges.json`

```js
    "badges": [
        "badge1",
        "badge2",
        "badge3"
    ]
```

and would like to edit and append the values to 1 string. My current solution is basically this:

```py
for x in data["badges"]:
   if x == "badge2":
       x = "badge2-A"
   if x == "badge3":
       x = "badge3-A"
   with open("badges.txt", "a") as f:
      f.write(f"{x} ")
with open("badges.txt", "r") as f:
   badges = f.read()
# print(badges) will return "badge1 badge2-A badge3-A "
```

I guess there isn't any real way to get around all the if-statements, but especially having to store all values in a separate file feels rather unclean at best. Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

This gives the same output and it is a bit more elegant because it excludes only the one that ends with a the string `"1"` and any other grade adds the `"-A"` to the end of the badge string.

Is this what you wanted?

```
for x in data['badges']:
    if x[-1] == "1":
        x = x
    else:
        x += "-A"

    with open("badges.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(f"{x} ")


with open("badges.txt", "r") as f:
    badges = f.read()
    print(badges)
```

output:

```
badge1 badge2-A badge3-A
```